# How I can get the full url path of an image on xml export on concrete 5?

Tags: xml, concrete5, concrete

I'm moving some articles from the concrete5 to wordpress using xml. The issue which I'm having has to do with the location of the image. I want to write a script that will read all the posts of the xml and replace the src path of the an image, with the actual image url path. The format of an image on the xml has the following format.

[http://www.local.app/download_file/view_inline/2040/](http://%20http://www.local.app/download_file/view_inline/2040/)

The 2040 is the image ID of the where the following url is the actual url path of that image.

[http://www.local.app/files/9014/6667/7722/IMG_2417.JPG](http://%20http://www.local.app/files/9014/6667/7722/IMG_2417.JPG)

How concrete generate this "9014/6667/7722"? I want to understand the file structure for images for concrete 5. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are pretty random, there is no reversible logic for it - its there to prevent filenames from clashing in the same directory as best as possible.

If you are writing a script to produce the XML within Concrete5 (build a Page List template) then you can request all the page content you want in the format you want, you can get the full image path then rather than the download use using

```
 $image->getRelativePath(true)
```